# Inverse Condition

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

Given a matrix $H \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times K}$, the new matrix $W$ is defined as
$$ W = H^T H,$$

where $T$ denotes the transpose operator.

I know that $W$ is invertible if $M \geq K$, but how can I prove it?
Thank you!

Comment: This will not work without additional assumptions, as the zero matrix would give a counterexample.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch : Do you mean that I should only add the nonzero condition?

Comment: $Wx=0\iff Hx=0$  so if $W$ is invertible then $H$ must have zero nullspace, that is, columns of $H$ are linearly independent.